# Log notices with Npgsql and EF Core

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, ef-core-5.0

I'm using Npgsql 5 with EF Core 5.

I added `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Information"` to my `appsettings.json`.

Suppose I have a sql command that includes this:

```sql
RAISE NOTICE 'foo';
```

How do I configure the provider to log that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL notices are raised by the Npgsql ADO.NET provider as a regular .NET event. You can register a handler for it as follows:

```cs
conn.Notice += (_, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.Notice.MessageText);
```

You can replace Console.WriteLine with anything that would log it to your logging framework.

There is currently no integration to automatically route this via EF Core's logging, I've opened https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2106 to do this for 7.0.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed (pun intended) the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-SEVERITY-LEVELS) mention "DEBUG1".."DEBUG5", but [elsewhere](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE) they mention only "DEBUG". The provider throws if I use anything other than "DEBUG". Is this correct? For my needs I don't need such fine-grained detail, but I'm curious if I'm using it correctly.